# Why am I getting a conversion function error?

Tags: c++, strlen, file-read

I have to read in an external file called text.txt. The file could contain a lot of data (and def > 83 chars) and I want to ignore the spaces. Then I need to get the total amount of chars in the file (not incl. spaces). I have to use strlen. I am getting a conversion type error which is confusing because I thought strlen returns an int. The error is on strlen(inputString) and more specifically on (inputString).

int main() {

```
fstream inFile;
string inputString;

inFile.open("text.txt", ios::in);

if (inFile) {
    getline(inFile, inputString, ' ');
    while (inFile)
    {
        int tempStringLength = strlen(inputString);
        int total = 0;
        total += tempStringLength;
    }
}
else
    cerr << "Unable to open file text.txt";
    exit(1);

    return 0;
```

}

I expect the total to be the total # of chars in the file.

Comment: `I am getting a conversion type error` Please, paste the error to the question so we can see it too.

Comment: Don't use `exit(1)` without a reason. It messes with the control flow of the program. You can replace it with `return 1`. This `return 0` is redundant. Program will never reach that point because there is `exit(1)` before that.

Comment: OK, my bad. This `return 0` probably won't be redundant when you fix indentation and add missing braces.

Answer (score 0):

The `strlen` function returns a `size_t` result which is usually equivalent to `unsigned int` on your platform.

Also, I haven't tried your code but it reads like an infinite loop. You might want to rearrange it like the following:

```cpp
int main() {

fstream inFile;
string inputString;

inFile.open("text.txt", ios::in);

unsigned int total = 0;
if (inFile) {
    while (inFile)
    {
        getline(inFile, inputString, ' ');

        unsigned int tempStringLength =inputString.length();
        total += tempStringLength;

        //Or maybe combine the two previous statements into:
        //total += inputString.length();
    }
}
else
    cerr << "Unable to open file text.txt";
    exit(1);

    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: Also, `strlen` expects a `char[]` as input. I've changed that to be `string.length()` instead.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `unsigned int` instead of just `size_t`?

Comment: Less cognitive load.

Comment: Actually, I've meant this as a rhetorical question. There is no real reason ;)